# Using Docker linux container on windows server 2016 1607

Tags: docker, windows-server

I've been asked to install some docker images we've created with asp.net core 3.1 on a customer machine that runs Win Server 2016 1607.
As far as I've read the Linux Subsystem is avaiable with 1909 so I wa windering : does an hack exists? otherwise it's good to install vmware and host a linux machine so I can install the Docker engine and run our docker images from the vm? Does performance affects? 
Thanks

Comment: You don't have so much solutions, but instead of using vmware you could use HyperV to run a small Linux VM for docker. You should have hyperv available and should works fine. About the performance, you will have the perf you of your linux VM

Comment: @jmaitrehenry your solution sounds good, if you put it as the answer, I'll select as the good one